# gwt history management with html a tag and styling issues when using gwt hyperlink

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, history

I'm trying to make navigation with my sidebar and when I use  to implement history mechanism with value change handler the navigation works properly but **the style get damaged**  when i use html  the style works properly but I don't know how to attach value change handler to html AnchorElement if i used it instead of gwt HyperLink

first: how to make the style looks properly with Hyperlink as regural html  ?
second: is it better to use html  for navigation with history tokens and how ?

```
<li>

            <g:Hyperlink>
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>

                Blank Page // here the style go wrong
            </g:Hyperlink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index-rtl.html">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
                Dashboard // here the style goes fine
            </a>
        </li>
```

[image]

Comment: What does your CSS look like? And does it change anything if you use `<g:InlineHyperlink>` instead of `<g:Hyperlink>`?

Comment: Thank you it worked with inline hyperlink